# How to remove relatively aligned view and keep other views intact?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with removing views from relative view. The code below programatically adds phone fields and then appends switches below. When adding fields it's all good, but I can't find the way to easily remove them so i.e. there are three fields and I want to delete second or third the ones below are left without view they anchored to.

[image]

Code:

```
private int lastCreatedView;
    private int tokensIteration;
    private int addButtonId, switch1Id, switch2Id;
    private ArrayList<Integer> editTextsIds = new ArrayList<>();
    private Contact contact;

    private void setPhoneField(String number){
        EditText editText = new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.ContactDetailsEditText));
        editText.setId(View.generateViewId());
        editText.setText(number);
        editText.setHint(R.string.contact_details_activity_hint_phone_number);
        editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        editText.setEms(10);
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        editText.setImeOptions(tokenizer != null && tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()
                ? EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT : EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

        editTextsIds.add(editText.getId());

        TextInputLayout til = new TextInputLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.ContactDetailsEditText));
        til.setId(View.generateViewId());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textInputLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int viewToAttach = lastCreatedView == 0 ? R.id.input_layout_company : lastCreatedView;
        textInputLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, viewToAttach);
        textInputLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, R.id.contact_photo);
        til.setLayoutParams(textInputLayoutParams);
        til.setTag(editTextsIds.size());

        lastCreatedView = til.getId();

        ImageView phoneButton = new ImageView(this);
        phoneButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_phone_black_48dp);
        phoneButton.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        phoneButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
        phoneButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams phoneButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        phoneButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF, til.getId());
        phoneButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, til.getId());
        phoneButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, til.getId());
        phoneButton.setLayoutParams(phoneButtonParams);
        phoneButton.setTag(editTextsIds.size());
        phoneButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
            startActivity(call);
        });

        til.addView(editText);

        contactContainer.addView(til);
        contactContainer.addView(phoneButton);

        ImageView removeNumber = new ImageView(this);
        removeNumber.setId(View.generateViewId());
        removeNumber.setVisibility(tokensIteration > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        removeNumber.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams removeNumberParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        removeNumberParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, til.getId());
        removeNumberParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, til.getId());
        removeNumberParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, til.getId());
        removeNumber.setLayoutParams(removeNumberParams);
        removeNumber.setTag(editTextsIds.size());
        removeNumber.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            for(View v : getViewsByTag(contactContainer, view.getTag()))
                contactContainer.removeView(v);

        });

        if(tokensIteration > 0) contactContainer.removeView(findViewById(addButtonId));
        ImageView addNumber = new ImageView(this);
        addNumber.setId(View.generateViewId());
        addNumber.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
        addNumber.setPadding(tokensIteration > 0 ? 5 : 0, 0, 0, 0);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams addNumberParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        addNumberParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, removeNumber.getId());
        addNumberParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, removeNumber.getId());
        addNumberParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, removeNumber.getId());
        addNumber.setLayoutParams(addNumberParams);
        addNumber.setTag(editTextsIds.size());
        addNumber.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Function not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                setPhoneField("");
                setSwitches();
            }
        );

        addButtonId = addNumber.getId();

        contactContainer.addView(removeNumber);
        contactContainer.addView(addNumber);

        setSwitches();
    }

    void setSwitches(){

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams recordCallsParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        recordCallsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastCreatedView);
        recordCallsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START, lastCreatedView);
        recordCallsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END, lastCreatedView);

        if(switch1Id != 0 && switch2Id != 0){
            contactContainer.updateViewLayout(findViewById(switch1Id), recordCallsParams);
            return;
        }

        Switch recordCalls = new Switch(this);
        recordCalls.setText(R.string.contact_details_activity_record_calls);
        recordCalls.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        recordCalls.setSwitchPadding(5);
        recordCalls.setId(View.generateViewId());
        recordCalls.setLayoutParams(recordCallsParams);
        recordCalls.setChecked(contact != null && contact.getIsRecordCalls());
        switch1Id = recordCalls.getId();

        Switch switchPrivate = new Switch(this);
        switchPrivate.setText(R.string.contact_details_activity_private_contact);
        switchPrivate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        switchPrivate.setSwitchPadding(5);
        switchPrivate.setId(View.generateViewId());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams switchPrivateParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        switchPrivateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, recordCalls.getId());
        switchPrivateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START, recordCalls.getId());
        switchPrivateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END, recordCalls.getId());
        switchPrivate.setLayoutParams(switchPrivateParams);
        switchPrivate.setChecked(contact != null && contact.getIsPrivateContact());
        switch2Id = switchPrivate.getId();

        contactContainer.addView(recordCalls);
        contactContainer.addView(switchPrivate);
    }

    private static ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, Object tag){
        ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
        final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                views.addAll(getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
            }

            final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
            if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
                views.add(child);
            }
        }
        return views;
```

Comment: I agree with reply from donfuxx below but in case that is not an option for you maybe you can organize the fields in a listview. This way it can be more dynamic.

Comment: Could You elaborate more on that, please? You mean whole `phoneField` as an object/view to put in the list?

Comment: You can have a layout within the ListView with the layout containing an edittext. So each row of the ListView will be an EditText. You can update the ListView any time you need to add/remove a field.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to completely remove the view? If you just want to hide some view without messing with the layout you can set it to `INVISIBLE`:

```
phoneButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**BTW:** I'd recommend you use **layout resource files**. It is much easier to work with especially when your layouts get more complex and you get the idea to make your app compatible with multiple screen sizes, screen orientations etc.

Comment: I would love to make a phone field a layout resource view. For now, I just don't know how to implement it properly, especially when it comes to aligning